# Why can't ridge regression set slope to zero like LASSO does

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression

I know that LASSO penalizes certain coefficents to zero by taking absolut value. However, ridge makes penalty by taking square instead. I am wondering why this difference forbid ridge from setting coefficient to zero like LASSO does. Can anyone share some comment? Thank a lot.

Comment: You mean LASSO is artificially allowed to set coefficent to zero while ridge is not? I thought there are some mathematical reason behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from Wikipedia:

> LASSO AND RIDGE have different constraints: $||\beta||_1\leq t$ for
>   LASSO and $||\beta||_2^2\leq t$ for RIDGE. The constraint region
>   defined by the $\ell ^1$ norm is a square rotated so that its corners
>   lie on the axes (in general a cross-polytope), while the region
>   defined by the $\ell ^2$ norm is a circle (in general an n-sphere),
>   which is rotationally invariant and, therefore, has no corners. A
>   convex object that lies tangent to the boundary is likely to encounter
>   a corner (or a higher-dimensional equivalent) of a hypercube, for
>   which some components of $\beta$ are identically zero, while in the
>   case of an n-sphere, the points on the boundary for which some of the
>   components of $\beta$  are zero are not distinguished from the others
>   and the convex object is no more likely to contact a point at which
>   some components of $\beta$ are zero than one for which none of them
>   are.